# Hide USB debug mode from app without rooting

Tags: applications, usb-debugging

How do I hide USB debugging mode from an app without rooting? Is it possible? I need to automate an app, but it has a USB debugging mode restriction. Please give me advice.

Comment: The Automate app do not have any "USB debug mode restriction", but it do include some optional features that rely on the system "USB debugging" or "Wireless debugging" developer options, i.e. the Android Debug Bridge. It's impossible to hide that either of those optional are enabled from other apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to bypass a debug mode check on an unrooted device is by manipulating the app itself.

However apps that check debug mode usually contain other protection measures like app signature self-checks, app integrity checks, or use an app obfuscator and protector or are even bound to Google Play Integrity.

What type of app are we talking about? An app you need for corporate access? Then it may be easier to talk to your company administrators if this restriction is configurable. Debug mode checks are often left-overs from old Android versions. Before Android 4.2 debug mode and Android Debug Bridge were very insecure and could act like a back door bypassing all security restrictions configured by the admins. At that time blocking adb was important for device security but nowadays that isn't necessary anymore as adb does no longer accept unauthorized connections.